# How to save data from stock tick data for particular timeframe

Tags: python, time, timedelta, stock

I'm receiving stock data every second in following format

> 'ohlc': {'close': 75.95, 'high': 83.5, 'low': 64.6, 'open':75.95},last_price': 75.0,timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 2, 11, 20, 15)

Since my trading time starts at 9:30 AM, I like to save the high and low of the stock of first five minutes only, so the high and low of the stock should be between the time 9:30 to 9:35 AM. following is the code i'm using but I'm not able to get the result.
Please help me out on this issue. basically i need to save data of 5 minutes, but i'm not able to understand how to do that.

```py
start_time = datetime.time(9, 30)
end_time = datetime.time(9, 35)
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
candle_start_time = current_time >= start_time and current_time <= end_time

breakout_time_start = current_time >= start_time

while candle_start_time is True:
    print('time started')
while current_time > end_time:
    print('time extended')
while current_time < end_time:
    print('time extended 1')
```

Comment: hey @tanjiro, in your question you mention you need to store some values within a certain time frame. in the code, you only provided something that goes around time.. How does the "data of 5 minutes" comes into play?

Comment: I don't understand your code. You have to check only `start_time <= time_from_timestamp <= end_time` when you get new data from server.

Comment: your `while` loop are useless. You always check the same value in `while`. Inside `while` you have to get new value from server and get time from tis data and use it in variable which you use in `while`

Comment: @stupidwolf  please leave the code aside , what i need is incoming data from 9:30 till 9:35AM ,should be saved , i.e High and Low values of the stock , and any change in data of high and low after 9:35 should not be considered in the saved variable.

Comment: @furas please leave the code aside , what i need is incoming data from 9:30 till 9:35AM ,should be saved , i.e High and Low values of the stock , and any change in data of high and low after 9:35 should not be considered in the saved variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example I use infinity loop - `while True` - to run all time (24 hours per day). It should get date from stock, check time in data and save it somewhere (file or database).

Eventually it can run commented part of code to stop it after 9:35 and then you have to start it next day before 9:30. You can start it manually or use some scheduler to start it - ie. `cronjob` on Linux.

```
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def get_from_stock():
    # TODO: get current data from stock
    return {
        'ohlc': {'close': 75.95, 'high': 83.5, 'low': 64.6, 'open':75.95},
        'last_price': 75.0,
        'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 2, 11, 20, 15),
    }

# --- main ---

start_time = datetime.time(9, 30)
end_time   = datetime.time(9, 35)

while True:

    data = get_from_stock()

    data_time = data['timestamp'].time()

    if start_time <= data_time <= end_time:
        print('Time:', data_time)
        print('High:', data['ohlc']['high'])
        print('Low:', data['ohlc']['low'])
        print('TODO: save it')

    #if data_time > end_time:
    #    print('Time:', data_time)
    #    print('It is end for today. Run again tomorrow before 9:00 AM.')
    #    break
```